# PHP when display_errors set to 0 500 in AJAX response

Tags: php, ajax, apache

I have a wired problem. When I set display_errors to 0 on production enviroment then AJAX request to some PHP script returns apache server error 500 and nothing works. When I set it to 1 then response is 200 and everything seems to be fine.

Question is what is the connection between display_errors and server error number. I don't get it and php.com doesn't explain this at all.

Moreover I have set error_log but there is no erros logged in either display_errors is set 1 or 0. Does anybody have this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

> Question is what is the connection between display_errors and server error number. I don't get it and php.com doesn't explain this at all.

`display_errors` is a PHP internal method that is used with errors coming from PHP. Server errors are coming from Apache and do not directly relate to PHP* ([list of HTTP Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html))

* – although PHP is able to send HTTP Status Codes

Comment: Check Apache's own error log. Apache will use it own error logs, and not PHP's to log such things.